# JavaScript only working on some pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following javascript to allow me to highlight a tr row when clicking on it

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', '#D3D3D3');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});

$('table tr').click(rowclick)
```

[This works fine here.](http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=Haydock&time=2:10)

But if I select [this](http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=Haydock&time=3:50), it does not work and I cant understand why as it uses the same code

the full JavaScript is as follows

```
var ie = document.all
var ns = document.getElementById && !ie
function rowclick(e) {
var obj = ns ? e.target : event.srcElement
if (obj.tagName=="TD") {

obj.onblur=function() {

}
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', '#D3D3D3');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});




$('table tr').click(rowclick)

document.onclick=rowclick

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



      function drawChart() {




        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  <?php echo $data; ?>   ]);



        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ <?php echo $datagoing; ?>   ]);


        var options = {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            legend: 'none',
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px',
               chartArea: { height :"95%", width:"95%" },

        };

        var options2 = {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            legend: 'none',
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px',
               chartArea: { height :"95%", width:"95%" },
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart<?php echo $loop ?>'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechartgoing<?php echo $loop ?>'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);

      }
```

Comment: Why isn't the last line inside your document ready handler, and what's `rowclick`? Do you get any errors in the browser console on the page where it doesn't work?

Comment: When I look into console got this "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.mr-tipster.com/include/ADAM.CG%20PRO.otf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

Comment: Each of your `<tr>` is rendering a `<script>` tag. There are multiple scripts on the page.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to see what´s happening since every `<tr>` you got has its own definition of your method . Try cleaning up your code and creating a .js file for your javascript. That might help you see what´s going on

Comment: i had added the full javascript for the page .